# Add logger to an existing chat app

Tags: node.js, winston, bunyan

I'd like to log usernames/dates of people coming in and out a [let's chat](https://github.com/sdelements/lets-chat/) server instance. I was told bunyan and winston are good candidates but I have no clue on how to implement them on this specific project.

I'm not sure on which file I have to instantiate them and how to catch username when login and when logout. My bet is in [controllers/account.js](https://github.com/sdelements/lets-chat/blob/350ecc6c57ae4b87ff82af0848e914ff43ff3ab8/app/controllers/account.js) but it's clearly out of my knowledge.

As a result I'd really like to obtain a rotated file with :

```
20171104-15:10:14 - LOGIN username with IP x
[...]
20171104-19:23:15 - LOGOUT username
```

Comment: Morgan is primarily used to capture http network traffic.  Try using pino/bunyan/winston for logging.  At a bare minimum, put a `log.info()` statement right after a successful login and then after a successful logout.

Comment: Ok, let's edit the topic with this info, thanks

Comment: @VtoCorleone I see a success login case in [login.js](https://github.com/sdelements/lets-chat/blob/1ae835fea4db48ea1ab0166991f1268df6241a96/media/js/login.js#L21). Should I add my log.info() there ?

Comment: Depends on what you want to log.  But yea, I imagine there is some sort of `.login(user, pass)` function and in the result of that, add `log.info('LOGIN username with IP x')`

Answer (score 0):

Got something I'm happy with :

1. added ***console.log('LOGIN', d);*** and ***console.log('LOGOUT', d);*** in
   [room.js](https://github.com/sdelements/lets-chat/blob/master/app/core/presence/room.js)
2. use pm2 and pm2-logrotate module to start my app, store logs
   end rotate them

Thanks to @VtoCorleone for his indications

Since there are certainly better ways to achieve this, I welcome other ideas.